# Storing data in shared preferences not working

Tags: android

I am working on android shared preferences. My requirement is when app opens, an edittextbox with submit button will
come. When submit button is clicked it will move to second page. Here, after closing the app and if I open again then
the second page should open directly. I am using auto login functionality. So for that I used shared preferences concept. But my code is not working. When I 
am opening the app again it is displaying the first page only.

Please help me with this issue.

My Code:

```
Page1:

    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE);

}

public void submit(View v) 
{

   userphnnumber = edt.getText().toString().trim();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();

editor.putString("UserName", userphnnumber);

editor.commit();

}

Page2:

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", 0);
        myVal = mPreferences.getString("UserName", null);
        System.out.println("the myval" + myVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside onCreate of the first 'page', do this.

```
mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myVal = mPreferences.getString("UserName", null);
if(myVal != null) {
     startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondPage.class));
}
```

Inside the submit function, do this.

```
String userphnnumber = edt.getText().toString().trim();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("UserName", userphnnumber);
editor.commit();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi thanks for the response..u told to keep in oncreate of first page...is that we should keep in first page or second page?

Comment: The `if()` check should be in the first page's onCreate so that, if the user is already submitted the phone number in a prior run, we can move onto the second page instead of staying on the first page. FYI : We don't call screens `pages` in Android, it is generously called `Activities` :)

Comment: Hi thank you..its working fine...also I need to store arraylist in sharedpref. Can u plz tell me how to store an arraylist in sharedpref?

Comment: If it is a simple list of Strings or so, you can use `editor.putStringSet("key", Set<String> arrayOfStrings);` For other data types, you need to use a way of representing it in one of the types supported by the preference editor.